# AWS APi Gateway VPC LINK - Make sure you are passing in a Gzip Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip, aws-api-gateway

I am using VPC link in API GATEWAY to connect to rest service in EC2 instance. However, octet stream responses are not getting correctly passed through. Error getting at client side is "Make sure you are passing in a Gzip Stream". Do I need to make any changes in API gateway or in Spring REST service headers? REST service returns the correct response if invoked directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! Resolved it. 
Added "Accept-encoding" : "identity" header in client side. 
in API Gateway setting, enabled "content encoding".

worked like a charm :)

PS: Make sure you deploy the API even though it is just settings!!